# Add item to input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add elements to an input field, it works by writing any content and then you hit the Enter key, so, the element its append to the input field, how can I do that? Maybe you can recommend me any jQuery Library?

Here you can see a picture:

[image: adding items to input field]

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a library bootstrap-tags

https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput

or any library that uses the principles of chips in material design

https://material.io/design/components/chips.html